# The authorization popup for the Google Marketplace whitescreens and doesn't close after install and other problems with the install page

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

When a user goes to my unlisted [marketplace app page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pingboard-development-pre/amelcfbelhalllggacpmnnojmalfbhfn) and installs my app the authorization popup window just white screens and doesn't close.  If I manually close the popup everything moves on like normal.  I have a suspicion that it's because my app is unlisted, since I haven't seen the issue with other marketplace apps, but as of right now I can't change that.

Another issue we've had with that page is the `Integrate with Google` button doesn't seem to respect the current profile the user is using.  It always seems to always use the default profile which can be confusing for the user if they wanted to use a different google profile they were currently using.

*note: the app url i've posted is used for local development but it happens on our production app as well*

[image]

Comment: Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console? Does it happen consistently?

Comment: No errors, it happens every time if you are on that kind of details page.  The `Integrate with Google` button works if you install it through the google apps admin panel but you can't direct link to that.

Comment: I got the white screen the first time I tried to install, but after cancelling and trying again it shows the auth fine. Have you found something different?

Comment: On the stand alone page I get every time I'm logged in.  If I have to login I don't get it.

Comment: Can you try creating a new listing and see if it suffers from the same issue?

Comment: I created a whole new list and project and got the same issue.  If I'm logged in it just doesn't work.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pingboard-development-pro/kaknelcnagbmmleglflekgllnilcjdpf

Comment: Also we've had a lot of people try this out and have the same results.

Comment: What scopes are your requesting? I'd like to try to replicate it on my own account.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group, https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Comment: Filed a bug - I can reproduce with that test listing.

Comment: Steve, for both bugs? Or just the whitescreen?  I think the `Integrate with Google` bug is actually a bigger issue.

Comment: Hi guys, was this ever resolved?  Running into the same issue on our unlisted app.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, still haven't heard back from anyone at google.